# By using some categories. I don't want to show a div

Tags: html, vue.js

The issue I have occurs when a user enters a category. Categories like electronics, toys, and cars are written using v-if condition. So while we enter these three categories in the category field I don't want to show the radio button checked.

Here I have tried this by using like  v-if="(category != 'Electronics')||(category != 'Toys')||(category != 'cars')" this condition but here this "||" condition is not working.

```
*input field for entering a category*
<div><input type="text" v-model="category" placeholder="Search your category"></div>
```

```
<div v-if="(category != 'Electronics')||(category != 'Toys')||(category != 'cars')">
    <h1>Consumer</h1>
    <div class="radio_select">
        <input type="radio" v-model="picked" value="consumer">
        <label>Personal Ad:</label>
        <p>Personal ads can be posted one ad per month, which will appear with "sale by owner tag"</p><br>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" id="business" name="flag" value="business" v-model="picked">
            <label>Business Ad:</label>
            <p>Do you want to upgrade to business account to post more <br>ads per month</p>
            <span class="prev_next">
            <button class="prev_next_btn" @click.prevent="prev()">Previous</button>
            <button class="prev_next_btn" @click.prevent="next()">Next</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**vue.js**

```
<script>
    Vue.use(VueFormWizard)
new Vue({
 el: '#q-vikreya',

    components: {
        "vue-form-g": VueFormGenerator.component
    },

    data() {
        return {
        step:1,
        category:'',
        model:'',
        formOptions: {
            validateAfterLoad: true,
            validateAfterChanged: true
        }
    };
   },
<!--/ By using this delimiters we were able to fix the vue.js compatibility with django. since the curly braces between django and-->
<!--    // vue.js conflicted, delimiters helped here to solve the conflicts-->
    delimiters: ["<%","%>"],
        ready: function() {
        console.log('ready');
    },

 methods: {
    prev(currentStep) {
      if(this.checkForm()) {
          if (currentStep === 4) {
             this.step = 3
          } else {
             this.step--;
          }
      }
    },
    next(currentStep) {
      if(this.checkForm()) {
        if (currentStep === 4) {
          this.step = 5
        } else {
          this.step++;
        }
      }
    },
    checkForm: function (e) {
      if (this.category && this.title) {
        return true;
      }

      this.errors = [];

      if (!this.category) {
        this.errors.push('Name required.');
      }
      if (!this.title) {
        this.errors.push('Age required.');
      }

      e.preventDefault();
    },
      submitForm: function(){
            axios({
                method : "POST",
                url: "{% url 'PostAd' %}", //django path name
                headers: {'X-CSRFTOKEN': '{{ csrf_token }}', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                data : {"category":this.category, "title":this.title,
                "address":this.address,
                "city": this.city,
                "state": this.state,
                "zip": this.zip,
                "price": this.price,
                "description": this.description,
                "radio_price": this.radio_price,
                "Job_title": this.model,
                },//data
              }).then(response => {
              console.log("response");
              console.log(response.data);
                  this.success_msg = response.data['msg'];
                 window.location.replace('{% url "classifieds" %}')  // Replace home by the name of your home view

              }).catch(err => {
                     this.err_msg = err.response.data['err'];
              console.log("response1");
              console.log(err.response.data);

              });

          },
  },
})

</script>
```

Comment: So if I type let's say "elect" the radio will be shown but in the case of typing a category name completely it will disappear, right?

Comment: Honestly, it's not clear what you want to do. But this `(category != 'Electronics') || (category != 'Toys') || (category != 'Cars')` condition will **ALWAYS** be `true`. Read the documentation, you just don't understand how it works `||`

Comment: if we enter a category electronics, toys, cars in a category field. Then if caategory enter i want to hide that personal AD and business Ad radio button div